# Sort list by string field of class

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have a list of objects, each with time data, id numbers, and a string descriptor in the type field. I wish to pull all the values to the front of the list with a certain string type, while keeping the order of those list elements the same, and the order of the rest of the list elements the same, just attached to the back of those with my desired string.

I've tried, after looking for similar SE questions,

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.type.Equals("Auto"));
```

which has no effect, though all other examples I could find sorted by number rather than by a string.

List Objects class definition:

```
public class WorkLoad
{
    public long id;
    public DateTime timestamp;
    ...
    public String type;
}

...create various workload objects...
schedule.Add(taskX)

schedule.OrderBy(x => x.type.Equals("Manual"));
//has no effect currently
```

Comment: You have to use `OrderByDescending` if you want all autos first, `Equals` returns a `bool`, `true` is greater than `false`.

Comment: The difficult thing seems to be keeping the original order in the two groups. How is the original ordering done? Is it possible to "sort" for this `type` _before_ the original sorting?

Comment: Everything else should be sorted by time, I'm adding workload objects to my list, which will all be timestamped with the time they are added. So could sorting into two groups, then sorting by time within each group, be feasible? I'm trying to keep time-complexity down.

And OrderByDescending hasn't helped unfortunately, @TimSchmelter

Comment: list items class definition and some data sample would make your question *much* clear

Comment: @alzinos: then use `OrderByDescending(x => x == "Auto").ThenBy(x => x.timestamp)`. But it won't fix your issue. You have to show sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a sorted list I think the fastest way to resort it by "having a type of auto or not" without losing the original order (and without having to resort all over again) could be this:

```
var result = list.Where(x => x.type.Equals("Auto"))
                 .Concat(list.Where(x => !x.type.Equals("Auto")))
                 .ToList();
```

---

Update:

You commented that "everyting else should be sorted by time", so you can simply do this:

```
var result = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.type.Equals("Auto"))
                 .ThenBy(x => x.Time).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple orderings in a sequence:

```
list.OrderBy(x => x.type == "Auto" ? 0 : 1).ThenBy(x => x.type);
```

Comment: OP said in comments that "Everything else should be sorted by time", so that `x.type` should actually be `x.timestamp`.

Comment: `OrderByDescending(x => x == "Auto").ThenBy(x => x.timestamp)`. But neither your nor mine will fix OP's issue. He needs to show sample data